# Print every record of an array on the same page with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop

I have an array with a variable amount of records. And I want to print every record of the array in the same html page. I prefer it to display in a list.

I have the following code. However this does only print the last record of the array because it overwrites the previous record in my html ul-element.

```
for (var i = 0; i < feedbackGeenLid.length; i++)
{
document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML= ("<li>"+feedbackGeenLid[i] + "</li>");
}
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to realize this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code keeps replacing the innerHTML you need to add to it.

```
document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML += ("<li>"+feedbackGeenLid[i] + "</li>");
                                              ^
                                              |
                                              Added + here
```

For better performance build one string and set it to innerHTML at the end of the loop.

```
var out = "";
for (var i = 0; i < feedbackGeenLid.length; i++)
{
  out += "<li>"+feedbackGeenLid[i] + "</li>";
}
document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML= out;
```

Another option, use [appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild)

Answer (score 1):

you are rewriting the content in each loop. use a variable to concatenate the content and then put it in the element:

```
var html = '';
for (var i = 0; i < feedbackGeenLid.length; i++)
{
 html += "<li>"+feedbackGeenLid[i] + "</li>";
}

document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML= html;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This method did the job as well.